# Iterating over an unknown number of lists referenced by dictionary key to allow comparison of values within each list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I recently started writing a small script where my intent is to input a directory full of files (eBooks in this case epub,mobi,djvu,pdf) find files that match each other in (almost) every way except extension (e.g. Multiple eBook file formats for the same 'book'), create a directory for that 'book' and place the files within the directory for easy importing into Calibre.

I decided on a data structure for the files that was a dict of lists, where the filenames are grouped by extension (key) into a list (value). If that wasn't clear, this is my mockup of the structure: {fileExtension:[fileName,fileName,...],fileExtension:[fileName,fileName,...]...}

The problem I have run into is in order to match up the individual values in each list, grouped by key I can't just use a nest of for-loops if I don't necessarily know how many keys I'm going to have.

Writing this in Python 2.7.2 under Windows 64-bit environment

Code:

```
import glob

workDirectory = 'E:\Some eBooks'
fileExtensions  = ['mobi','epub','pdf','djvu']

# Create an appropriate holding structure for our results {fileExtension:[fileName,fileName,...]}
foundFiles = dict.fromkeys(fileExtensions,[])

for ext in fileExtensions:
    print('Looking for ' + ext + ' files in ' + workDirectory)
    for file in glob.glob(workDirectory + '/*.' + ext):
        foundFiles[ext].append(file)
```

I know I can write the looping action against the file contents 'statically' knowing that there will be four keys created from `fileExtensions` but later on once things are working, I would like the code to take an arbitrary number of values to `fileExtensions` via argparse.

I guess my core question is, how do I loop over multiple lists, using a variable number of dictionary keys as the reference to the lists in the same iteration? If I knew the static names of each list and that each of them had the same number of values I would do:

```
for one, two, three, four in list1 list2 list3 list4:
    ......
```

But I know doing this wont work since I don't immediately know how many lists I will be looping over and I do know the number of iterations required for each list won't match up.

I have a sinking feeling that I'm overthinking this problem to the point of confusing myself. Perhaps a set of nested lists would work, but for some reason I thought I could do this in a more straightforward manner.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly useful to be able to iterate through the lists in parallel, so to speak. Suppose you have a directory with avatar.pdf, batman.pdf, and batman.djvu. Your program will create a dict like this: `{'pdf': ['avatar', 'batman'], 'djvu': ['batman']}`. Iterating through the lists in parallel, you'll first get `(avatar.pdf, batman.djvu)`. In the next iteration you'll get `(batman.pdf,)`. Even though you have a duplicate of batman, you won't find it by looking through the lists in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To traverse `workDirectory` directory tree and collect all files with `fileExtensions` extensions:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

fileExtensions  = ('.mobi', '.epub', '.pdf', '.djvu')

foundFiles = defaultdict(list)
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(workDirectory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(fileExtensions):
           basename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
           foundFiles[basename].append(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
```

The format of `foundFiles` is the same as in [@jterrace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8537959/4279):

```
{
    "batman": [
        "/some/path/batman.pdf", 
        "/other/path/batman.mobi"
    ], 
    "superman": [
        "/some/path/superman.epub", 
        "/other/path/superman.djvu"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out now but I had only intended on working in the specified directory and not recursing it with os.walk. How can I limit it's recursion level by n levels? If I can control that, this may end up being useful for more than this one use case (Plus i'm learning a lot of cool things). Thanks!

Comment: @Robert McGinley: to avoid recursion just add [`break`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) or use [@jterrace's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8537959/4279).

Comment: Everything said and done, this became the core of the script which worked quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead, I would store the found files by their name so they are grouped as soon as you read them. Like this:

```
foundFiles = {}
for ext in fileExtensions:
    print('Looking for ' + ext + ' files in ' + workDirectory)
    for file in glob.glob(workDirectory + '/*.' + ext):
        basename = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
        grouped_files = foundFiles.get(basename, [])
        grouped_files.append(file)
        foundFiles[basename] = grouped_files
```

Now you have `foundFiles` where the keys are the base name of the file and the values are the paths to the files. Example:

```
{ 'batman': ['/some/path/batman.pdf', '/other/path/batman.mobi']
  'superman': ['/some/path/superman.epub', '/other/path/superman.djvu'] }
```

Comment: Ah, I like that. My only question is how basename will handle files with spaces. I don't believe dict keys can have spaces in them. I'll just have to swap the whitespace chars with something else. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working as the output from os.path.splitext is returning a tuple of ('basename','.ext') for each individual file. Ends up looking like {('basename','.ext):['filepath'],} where the list only contains the one file. just using the first value of the tuple is giving the intended result

Comment: @Robert McGinley: [dict keys can be any immutable type](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in particular any string (whether it has spaces or not), [example](https://ideone.com/enUx7).

Comment: @Robert McGinley: did you notice [`[0]`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) after `splitext()`?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I sure didn't when I was copying it over. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a simple list, containing all your files from all directories, and using regex, you could iterate and the list, and find all files matching the same filename as your current element?

Comment: Not a bad idea. For some reason I though this type of data structure would make things easier, until I ran face first into this brick wall.

Comment: You should give a shot with my advice, just in case.